# Не появляется окно с предложением запустить отладчик Visual Studio в Win10 во время запуска exe с исключением

Tags: c++, windows-10, отладка, visual-studio-2017

Как настроить Visual Studio Debugger, чтобы он мог запускаться при возникновении любого исключения (или при расстановке в коде DebugBreak) в любой программе (запуск любого exe-файла)?

Код для теста:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello\n";
    DebugBreak();            // <-------- тут
    std::cout << "World\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Windows 10
Visual Studio 2017:
Если запускать в студии по F5 (Start debugging), то отладчик останавливается на DebugBreak(), как и ожидалось.
Если запускать отдельно exe-файл, то выполнение прерывается и программа/консоль просто закрывается без какого-либо окна с предложением отладить программу.

Comment: Чтобы это окно появилось, отладчик должен быть уже запущен до возникновения исключения.

Comment: А как его запустить отдельно?

Comment: `devenv /debugexe "C:\MyApplication\Debug\MyApplication.exe"` Но вообще наверное проще запускать из самой студии

Comment: Спасибо, до этого как-то не додумался 
Сделал через студию File->Open и выбрал нужный exe-шник. Сработало на этом простеньком примере.
И уже на рабочем проекте: таким же образом запустил exe ( от которого у меня нет исходников) через студию, затем выполнение дошло до моего кода в отдельной dll и отладчик остановился в нужном месте. Спасибо еще раз

Comment: А еще вопрос, если я запускаю отладку одного exe-шника в студии, который будет стартовать другой процесс. И если в этом новом процессе будет исключение, то отладчик это отловит? Или нужно что-то дополнительно придумывать?

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vsdbgplat.MicrosoftChildProcessDebuggingPowerTool